# Does the javascript:winopen have a minimum width in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

I am trying to implement a "good" popup window in my website so I can show portfolio examples of some web banners. The user is given a "launch demo" button to click if they wish to see the banner in action. This works great in Firefox, Chrome & Safari (both PC & Mac).

Two of my 3 banners work fine in IE, but for some reason the 1st banner pops up 90 or so pixels wider than it should (it s/b 160px, the other 2 banners have 715px and 550px widths). I am still new to Javascript, so I am not sure if it could be a minimum width or where the issue might be? Any thought would be VERY helpful! Thanks!
Here is the Javascript code I am using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                <!--

                var win=null;
                function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll,pos){
                if(pos=="random"){LeftPosition=(screen.width)?Math.floor(Math.random()*(screen.width-w)):100;TopPosition=(screen.height)?Math.floor(Math.random()*((screen.height-h)-75)):100;}
                if(pos=="center"){LeftPosition=(screen.width)?(screen.width-w)/2:100;TopPosition=(screen.height)?(screen.height-h)/2:100;}
                else if((pos!="center" && pos!="random") || pos==null){LeftPosition=0;TopPosition=20}
                settings='width='+w+',height='+h+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes';
                win=window.open(mypage,myname,settings);}
                // -->
</script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
function winopen(url,a,b){
newwin=window.open(url,a,b)
}
// End -->
</script>
```

And here is the html it's acting on:

```
<h3>MAve Web Banner <a href="javascript:winopen('http://www.mightyjen.com/swf/MAve_FlashBanner_160x600.html','blank','width=160,height=600,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no')" class="formButton">Launch Demo</a></h3>
```

Comment: You should really consider using a lightbox for this instead of a real popup window. We aren't in year 2000 anymore. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes 100.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

I'd recommend checking the w3c website regarding standard object queries prior to asking here; folks tend to pettifog over these kind of things.

Comment: They're not perfect, but "bad" is somewhat opprobrious. That's not to say the site you've linked doesn't make a lot of good points, just shifting from one less than perfect reference to another isn't the solution. They've hit the nail on the head with the wikifying statement.

Comment: This is not the correct reason. IE cannot be smaller then 250 in width. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nevermet/archive/2009/12/29/the-minimum-ie-window-size.aspx